# SWRevealViewController and UINavigationControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swrevealviewcontroller

Ok, I'll start off without pasting code because I suspect my problem is conceptual regarding the use of SWrevealVC. I have the following storyboard:

[image: My Storyboard]

The frontView flow starts with a Navigation Control and works like a charm, the problem is the rear one, which starts with the menu TableView.
The menu has 2 items: favorites and called. Both of them fire a SWRevealViewControllerSegue to transition to a table view for displaying the results (same general data structure, they just come from 2 different "tables"). 
So clicking on Favorites fires a uitableview with the following bar:

[image: Favorites]

And clicking the first result, transitions to the details page with this bar:

[image: Details]

I have no back button! Without navigation controller, I'm not being able to add a bar item button, how can I solve this? I tried adding a navigation controller after the menu but it says I can't push a navigation controller. Help!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add manually a bar button in your viewDidLoad method for this.
Just like this:

```
SWRevealViewController *reveal = self.revealViewController;
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:reveal action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtn;
```

It works for me.By the way I am using XIB not a storyboard but it will surely work for storyboard also.